# passing a mmap pointer from C to python as a mmap object

Tags: python, c, pointers, mmap, word-wrap

I am trying to interface a C library (beaglebone PRU driver prussdrv.c) with Python. The particular function I want to access returns a mmap pointer as illustrated below:

```
int __prussdrv_memmap_init(void) {
      prussdrv.pru0_dataram_base = mmap(0, prussdrv.pruss_map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
         MAP_SHARED, prussdrv.mmap_fd, PRUSS_UIO_MAP_OFFSET_PRUSS);
      ...

int prussdrv_map_prumem(unsigned int pru_ram_id, void **address) {    
     switch (pru_ram_id) {
     case PRUSS0_PRU0_DATARAM:
          *address = prussdrv.pru0_dataram_base;
           break;

prussdrv_map_prumem (DATARAM[PRU_NUM], &pruDataMem);
pruDataMem_byte = (unsigned char*) pruDataMem;
```

I would like to encapsulate either pruDataMem or pruDataMem_byte and pass it to Python as a mmap object. Is there a straightforward way to do this? I've looked at capsule and ctypes but they do not appear to do what I am looking for?

Comment: Does it have to actually be an `mmap` object that you can manipulate, or just some buffer-like thing that you can treat as a string/list/iterator the same way you can with an `mmap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to create a Python `mmap` object out of a native mapping like this. The protocol isn't published, and neither is the internal format.

But of course [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules/mmapmodule.c) is available. So, as long as your mapping meets all the same criteria as one created by `new_mmap_object`, you could manually construct an `mmap_object` wrapping the information, and pass it back. (You can't *actually* access the `mmap_object` type, because it's not in any header file. But if you create an equivalent type, or just copy-and-paste the code, you'll be passing it around as a `PyObject *`, and as long as its type field points to the right type, it'll work.)

However, I'm not sure you need to do this. Do you really need an `mmap`, or just any buffer that you can treat as a string/list/iterator? Because the latter is a lot easier. For that, you can just create an [old-style buffer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/objbuffer.html#old-buffer-protocol) or [new-style buffer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#buffers-and-memoryview-objects) class—or, if you only need 2.7+, use the concrete [`memoryview`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) type. Conceptually, it seems to make sense that you're returning a view of the mapped memory, rather than the mapping itself, but I can imagine some use cases where this might be inappropriate.

Finally, you can always create a new class that exposes whatever interface you want around your mapping, and make it as much (or as little) like `mmap` as you want.

Comment: Yes, any type of buffer like access would work. I had started looking into manually putting a mmap object together based on the new_mmap_object code as you also suggested, but hopefully using the buffer class or memoryview will be easier than that. Thanks for the pointers! I'll start looking into them.

Comment: @cyann: What Python version(s) do you care about? You don't want to use the old concrete buffer classes in anything. Use `memoryview` if you can. If you need 2.6, you have to write your own new-buffer-protocol class, but that's pretty easy (and you can borrow liberally from 2.7's `memoryview`). If you need 2.5 or earlier, you have to implement the old buffer protocol—the best guidance there is that you don't have to implement everything in the protocol, just the parts your code needs.